# Android scrolling images

Tags: android

How do I implement image scrolling like in motors.co.uk app?
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.motors.activities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Gallery widget. It allows you to display a series of images and scroll through them horizontally.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example/